# FileReader onload not getting fired for second attempt in IE 11 after contents of the uploaded file is changed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, onload, filereader

`FileReader` `onload` not getting fired on second time when the same file still selected with IE11 but the contents of file has changed, it's getting fired all the time for FireFox,Chrome.

**Operation Details**

1. On First Click, its all okay for all browsers(but IE sometime still missing some words from file).
2. After that I changed the contents of the file.
3. And then I click second attempt to `btnDownload`, Firefox and Chrome still reading the updated contents. BUT IE DOES NOT WORK!

.html

```
<input type="file" id="fileSelect" style="" accept=".csv">

<a type="button"  class="btn" id="btnDownload" onclick="csvDownload()" 
download>  CSV DOWNLOAD  </a>
```

myjavascript.js

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileSelect"); //<input type="file" id="fileSelect">
var result = "";
readFile = function() {
changeAPInfoName();
if (!isFileSupported()) {
    console.log('The browser does not support the API.');

} else {
    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
           result = reader.result;

           alert("WANT TO GET HERE ,ALTHOUGH FILE CONTENTS ARE CHANGED.(IN IE 11)");            

           document.getElementById('MY_HIDDEN_FIELD').setAttribute('value',result);
      }

    reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);

    reader.onerror = function() {
         console.log('The file cannot be read.'+fileInput.files[0].fileName);
      };
}

// EVENT FOR DOWNLOAD BUTTON!!!!
function csvDownload(){
     readFile();  

     // using ajax to sent info from files and get download file.
}
```

Please help me with following issue.

1. How can I get to the line in reader.onload method although file contents are changed. `alert("WANT TO GET HERE ,ALTHOUGH FILE CONTENTS ARE CHANGED.(IN IE 11)");` .

Comment: try   reader.addEventListener("load", function (){      });

Comment: heh: `;btnDownload.click();` if that still doesn't do it in IE, then IE won't do it, plain and simple. for the other browsers, you don't actually even need to re-populate the input, just calling the FileReader() routine again will extract the new file contents, so in those browsers,  `;btnDownload.click();` (without messing with clicking the input) will magically work as expected, and if you poll it, you create a "watchfile"...

Comment: Thanks for your times. :) 
@Jois  : Where should I add that code. 'function (){}' means ???

Comment: Thanks for your times. ;) 
@dandavis : Where should I add 'btnDownload.click()' ?

Comment: you can call `setInterval(btnDownload.click.bind(btnDownload), 500)` from the end of the body once to keep it live updated up to the point of submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
reader.onload = function() {
       result = reader.result;

       alert("WANT TO GET HERE ,ALTHOUGH FILE CONTENTS ARE CHANGED.(IN IE 11)");            

       document.getElementById('MY_HIDDEN_FIELD').setAttribute('value',result);
  }
```

with

```
reader.addEventListener("load",function(){
result = reader.result;

           alert("WANT TO GET HERE ,ALTHOUGH FILE CONTENTS ARE CHANGED.(IN IE 11)");            

           document.getElementById('MY_HIDDEN_FIELD').setAttribute('value',result);
});
```

I hope this is helpful. I was facing the same problem and I used this method and it worked

**Example of working FileReader:**

```
<html>

<head>



    <script>


        function read(){
            //Select the element containing file
              var file =document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        //create a FileReader
        reader = new FileReader();
        //add a listener
        reader.addEventListener('load',function(){

            alert(reader.result);

        },false);

        if(file){
             //ReadFile
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);//You can read it in many other forms

        }
        }

    </script>



    </head>

    <body>

    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile"  onchange="read()">




    </body>

</html>
```

For more on FileReader check this document out : [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Thank you bro. But I can't get there with IE11. May I get jsfiddle link if you already have? I am feeling close to the answer. :)

Comment: Hey I have added a working filereader code run it in your pc. and check it out. If this was helpful dont forget to tick the answer. ThankYou

Comment: Sorry for my late reply Bro Jois. I still have problem. The IE can't read the latest updated file if file is chosen and edit the file and then read the file content. Could you please provide jsfiddle demo?